# How to check the version of oracle provider for ole-db. OraOLEDB.Oracle provider

Tags: oracle, oledb

How to check the version of oracle provider for ole-db.   OraOLEDB.Oracle provider  on windows 10 and windows 7 ?

Comment: It's the same version as the Oracle client - otherwise the provider does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for example tool [RegDllView](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/regdllview-view-all-registered-dll-files-windows). Search for "OraOLEDB", result could be this:

[image]

A simpler approach would be this navigate to your `ORACE_HOME\bin` directory and locate file `OraOLEDB??.dll`. Check version with right-hand mouse click -> Properties -> Details.

However, you just get the version of the file, it does not necessarily mean that this DLL is also registered and ready for use.

Or use this VBScript:

```
Option Explicit
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000

Dim Key, strComputer, objRegistry, strPath, arrKeys, fso
Dim strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue, uValue, ver

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
objRegistry.enumKey HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "CLSID", arrKeys

For Each key In arrKeys
    strKeyPath = "CLSID\" & key
    strValueName = "OLEDB_SERVICES"
    If objRegistry.GetDWordValue (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, strKeyPath, strValueName, uValue) = 0 Then  
        'get the (Default) value which is the name of the provider
        objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, strKeyPath, "", strValue
        If InStr(1, strValue, "OraOLEDB.Oracle", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' get expanded location
            objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, strKeyPath & "\InprocServer32", "", strPath

            ver = fso.GetFileVersion(strPath)
            Wscript.Echo strValue & " @ " & strPath & " -> " & ver
        End If
    End If 
Next
```

OLE DB provider may exist in 32-bit or/and in 64-bit, so you may execute the script twice:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe Print_OLE.vbs
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe Print_OLE.vbs
```