# Add providers to VS 2008 Connection Manager?

Tags: oracle, ssis, odbc, oledb, ssis-2008

With `Visual Studio 2008` I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database using `Oracle Provider to OLE DB` (the only Oracle driver available in dropdown), and I'm having issues with it. So I'm trying to add other drivers to that VS2008 "Connection Manager" dropdown. Unfortunately, I only see the ones in this screenshot

[image]

How can I add other drivers to this dropdown? When I create an ODBC driver, I see several other Oracle drivers to choose from that I don't see in the VS2008 dropdown.

[image]

Comment: ODBC != OLE DB. OLEDB is ancient.

Comment: But I can use an ODBC in ADO.NET.

Comment: Yes, there is a ODBC ado.net provider.

Comment: You stated "I'm having issues with it" - what kind of issues? Perhaps the can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You installed more than one Oracle Client, this is always a bad idea. Usually there is no reason to install more than one Oracle Client, i.e. one each for 32-bit and 64-bit.

For OLE DB you cannot install more than one driver (per architecture), see [Installation Considerations for Oracle Database Client](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTCLI/install.htm#NTCLI1281):

> You can install all Oracle components in multiple Oracle homes on the
>   same computer. However, some components can only support one active
>   instance at a time. This means that the current (latest) installation
>   renders the previous one inactive. These components are:
>
> - Oracle Administration Assistant for Windows
> - Oracle Provider for OLE DB

This is a limitation in [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model). So, you cannot add other providers, at least no other *Oracle Provider for OLE DB*

You **could** use the *Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle* (`MSDAORA`), however this has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-2017) for ages and it is really not recommended to use it.

Instead of OLE DB you could also use ODBC or use the **Oracle Data Provider for .NET**, you can download and install it from here: [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html)
As far as I know Visual Studio 2008 supports only .NET Framework only up to version 3.5, thus you would have to use the Oracle Data Provider for .NET 2.0, version 4 will not work.

Maybe this list provides an overview for you: [How to connect to Oracle 11 database from . net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999)

If you like to get a list of all OLE DB providers which are installed on your machine, check this one: [How to check the version of oracle provider for ole-db. OraOLEDB.Oracle provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326983/how-to-check-the-version-of-oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb-oracle-provider)